# How to repair door trim that was chewed by dog

Tags: repair, doors, frame

[image]

My brother's dog chewed/scratched my door frame in our apartment and I was looking for tips on how to fix this ourselves without hiring someone before we decide to move out, the apartment is pretty old so I was not sure just going to a home store would do us any good... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the casing sustained most of the damage. It appears to be aged pine or fir. The challenge will be finding a matching profile. You may need to replace the casing on the entire opening face so that the three pieces match.

Look for a molding with the same width as the original and a profile of similar style. Depth isn't critical as long as it's aesthetically similar. A miter saw and small trim nails will be needed. Chances are a couple coats of polyurethane varnish will give a similar look after some time for UV light to darken the pine.