# Dog ate/scratch edge of door, what can fix this?

Tags: door-frame, scratches

My dog scratched/ate the edge of the door. Ive searched up a couple of things, and they've said I'd need some wood fillings. I'll try and upload an image.

Its 8cm by 4cm area. Max depth is around 2-3mm of wood scratched, its pretty even.

Please let me know thank you.

Comment: Without a picture, there's not much more we can say beyond "wood filler would be a likely choice". Please [edit] the picture into your question as soon as possible. Also, don't forget to train the dog not to chew on the door or he's going to end up eating filler instead of wood. We found that hot sauce (like Tabasco™ Sauce) was a good deterrent. Maybe sprinkle some on _before_ repairing to dissuade him from chewing so he doesn't eat through the repair.

Comment: If scratched instead of chewed, a hot sauce might not work.

Comment: Or this? [How to repair door trim that was chewed by dog](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/79405/how-to-repair-door-trim-that-was-chewed-by-dog)

Comment: Or maybe this? [How can I repair damaged door casing?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/185862/how-can-i-repair-damaged-door-casing)

Comment: There are a lot of naughty dogs out there it seems :x

Comment: My dogs love Tabasco... it would be an enticement.